# Passing valued parameter to scons in command line?

Tags: scons

How do you guys pass valued parameter to scons ? I went through its [documentation](http://www.scons.org/documentation.php) and unfortunately it's still unclear to me. I've never used it before.

Please consider **[this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/SConstruct)** build script.

Here is code snippet from it

```
add_option( "boost-version", "boost version for linking(1_38)" , 1 , True , "boostVersion" )

boostVersion = GetOption( "boostVersion" )
if boostVersion is None:
    boostVersion = ""
else:
    boostVersion = "-" + boostVersion
```

I tried calling `scons --boost-version=1.51` and tried `scons --boostVersion=1.51` and none of it worked.

Comment: When you say "...none of it worked.", what happens exactly? Does SCons not accept the command line and exit? Or does it not correctly store the value in the `boostVersion` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use arguments:

You call `scons boost-version=1.51` on the commandline

Then, to fetch the value in the SConscript:

```
boostVersion = defaultBoostVersion
if 'boost-version' in ARGUMENTS: 
  boostVersion = ARGUMENTS["boost-version"]
```

or, as [elmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259371/elmo) suggested:

```
boostVersion = ARGUMENTS.get("boost-version", defaultBoostVersion)
```

The scons documentation have [more information](http://www.scons.org/doc/1.1.0/HTML/scons-user/x2361.html) the same page also describe how to use
`AddOption` command that you have tried earlier. It can be used also, but arguments are (to me at least) easier to understand.

Comment: Shorter (and I think more readable) way would be `boostVersion = ARGUMENTS.get("boost-version", defaultBoostVersion)`